# Refresh user-defined function when input values change

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have problem getting the user-defined function I created to refresh when my input values change. In fact, the input values are "governed" by another macro and that is why I think the function is not really triggered (in fact, it is getting refreshed but delayed by "1 step". And I am actually using Application.Volatile :) so can you please help me? :)

Here is the function:

```
Public Function AvColor(ByRef myRange As Range) As Double


ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Application.Volatile

 Dim Sum As Integer

 Sum = 0

 Dim Count As Integer

 Count = 0

 For Each Cell In myRange

 If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

Sum = Sum + 1

ElseIf Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Then

Sum = Sum + 2

ElseIf Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then

Sum = Sum + 3

ElseIf Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then

Sum = Sum + 4

ElseIf Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 33 Then

Sum = Sum + 5

ElseIf Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = Blank Then

Sum = Sum


End If

Count = Count + 1

Next Cell


AvColor = Round(Sum / Count)



ActiveSheet.Protect


 End Function
```

and here is my macro used for the whole sheet:

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim icolor As Integer
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Application.Volatile True
For i = 4 To 35

       If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(i, 15), Cells(i, 18))) Is Nothing Then

      For Each Cell In Range(Cells(i, 15), Cells(i, 18))

        'Increase 5

                If Cells(i, 4).Value = 1 Then

             If Cell = Blank Then

                 icolor = Blank

            ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 5) Then

                icolor = 3
            ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 7) Then

                icolor = 44

            ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 9) Then
                icolor = 6
            ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i, 11) Then

                icolor = 43
            ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 11) Then

                icolor = 33
            Else
                'Whatever

            End If


       '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Increase 3

        ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 2 Then

               If Cell = Blank Then

                 icolor = Blank

            ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 5) Then
                icolor = 3

            ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i, 7) Then
                icolor = 44

            ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 7) Then
                icolor = 6
            'ElseIf cell < Cells(i, 11) Then
                'icolor = 43

            'ElseIf cell >= Cells(i, 13) Then
                'icolor = 33

            Else
                'Whatever

            End If

       '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'Decrease 5

        ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 3 Then

             If Cell = Blank Then

                 icolor = Blank

            ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 5) Then

                icolor = 3
            ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 7) Then

                icolor = 44

            ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 9) Then
                icolor = 6
            ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 11) Then

                icolor = 43
            ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i, 11) Then

                icolor = 33
            Else
                'Whatever

            End If

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'Decrease 3


        ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 4 Then

                     If Cell = Blank Then

                 icolor = Blank

            ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 5) Then

                icolor = 3
            ElseIf Cell >= Cells(i, 7) Then

                icolor = 44

            ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 7) Then
                icolor = 6
           'ElseIf cell > Cells(i, 11) Then

                'icolor = 43
            'ElseIf cell <= Cells(i, 13) Then

                'icolor = 33

            Else

                'Whatever

            End If


         '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'Non-Linear 5

        ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 5 Then

                    If Cell = Blank Then

                 icolor = Blank


           ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 5) Then

                icolor = 3

           ElseIf Cell > Cells(i + 1, 5) Then

                icolor = 3
            ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 7) Then

                icolor = 44

            ElseIf Cell > Cells(i + 1, 7) Then

                icolor = 44

            ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 9) Then

                icolor = 6

            ElseIf Cell > Cells(i + 1, 9) Then

                icolor = 6

             ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 11) Then
                icolor = 43

             ElseIf Cell > Cells(i + 1, 11) Then
                icolor = 43
            ElseIf Cell >= Cells(i, 11) Then

                icolor = 33

            ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i + 1, 11) Then

                icolor = 33

            Else
                'whatever
        End If

                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'Non-Linear 3

        ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 6 Then

          If Cell = Blank Then

                 icolor = Blank

           ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 5) Then

                icolor = 3
            ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 7) Then

                icolor = 44

             ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i, 9) Then
                icolor = 6
            ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i, 11) Then

                icolor = 44

             ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 11) Then

                icolor = 3
            Else
                'whatever
        End If



        Else

        Msg = "Error"

        End If
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor



    Next Cell


    End If
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    End Sub**
```

Comment: First, you can't change sheet protection in a UDF. Second, `Application.Volatile` is meaningless in anything other than a UDF. Third, changing cell colours doesn't trigger a recalculation so your Change event will have to do that after it changes the cell colours. Finally, don't use colours as data. :)

Comment: Hi @Rory, thank you for your answer : can you Please help me adding this Change event that will trigger the calculation? In fact, I need to use the colours so if not as Data, what do you propose? Thanks

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you for your answer : can you Please help me adding this Change event that will trigger the calculation? In fact, I need to use the colours so if not as Data, what do you propose? Thanks – @Rory

Comment: Sorry I am discovering how to tag the previous commenter :S

Answer (score 0):

First remove the Unprotect and Protect statements from your function. Then alter the Change code to this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim icolor                As Long
    Dim i                     As Long
    Dim rCell                 As Excel.Range

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(4, 15), Cells(35, 18))) Is Nothing Then
        For i = 4 To 35

            For Each Cell In Range(Cells(i, 15), Cells(i, 18))

                'Increase 5

                If Cells(i, 4).Value = 1 Then

                    If Cell.Value2 = vbNullString Then

                        icolor = xlColorIndexNone

                    ElseIf Cell.Value2 < Cells(i, 5).Value2 Then

                        icolor = 3
                    ElseIf Cell.Value2 < Cells(i, 7).Value2 Then

                        icolor = 44

                    ElseIf Cell.Value2 < Cells(i, 9).Value2 Then
                        icolor = 6
                    ElseIf Cell.Value2 <= Cells(i, 11).Value2 Then

                        icolor = 43
                    ElseIf Cell.Value2 > Cells(i, 11).Value2 Then

                        icolor = 33
                    End If


                    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                    'Increase 3

                ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 2 Then

                    If Cell.Value2 = vbNullString Then

                        icolor = xlColorIndexNone

                    ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 5) Then
                        icolor = 3

                    ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i, 7) Then
                        icolor = 44

                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 7) Then
                        icolor = 6

                    End If

                    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

                    'Decrease 5

                ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 3 Then

                    If Cell.Value2 = vbNullString Then

                        icolor = xlColorIndexNone

                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 5) Then

                        icolor = 3
                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 7) Then

                        icolor = 44

                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 9) Then
                        icolor = 6
                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 11) Then

                        icolor = 43
                    ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i, 11) Then

                        icolor = 33
                    End If

                    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

                    'Decrease 3


                ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 4 Then

                    If Cell.Value2 = vbNullString Then

                        icolor = xlColorIndexNone

                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 5) Then

                        icolor = 3
                    ElseIf Cell >= Cells(i, 7) Then

                        icolor = 44

                    ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 7) Then
                        icolor = 6
                    End If


                    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

                    'Non-Linear 5

                ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 5 Then

                    If Cell.Value2 = vbNullString Then

                        icolor = xlColorIndexNone

                    ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 5) Then

                        icolor = 3

                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i + 1, 5) Then

                        icolor = 3
                    ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 7) Then

                        icolor = 44

                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i + 1, 7) Then

                        icolor = 44

                    ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 9) Then

                        icolor = 6

                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i + 1, 9) Then

                        icolor = 6

                    ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 11) Then
                        icolor = 43

                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i + 1, 11) Then
                        icolor = 43
                    ElseIf Cell >= Cells(i, 11) Then

                        icolor = 33

                    ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i + 1, 11) Then

                        icolor = 33

                    End If

                    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

                    'Non-Linear 3

                ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 6 Then

                    If Cell.Value2 = vbNullString Then

                        icolor = xlColorIndexNone

                    ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 5) Then

                        icolor = 3
                    ElseIf Cell < Cells(i, 7) Then

                        icolor = 44

                    ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i, 9) Then
                        icolor = 6
                    ElseIf Cell <= Cells(i, 11) Then

                        icolor = 44

                    ElseIf Cell > Cells(i, 11) Then

                        icolor = 3
                    End If
                Else

                    Msg = "Error"

                End If
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor

            Next Cell

        Next i
    End If
    Application.Calculate
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi again, thanks a lot :) it works now. Yet with this update, after the first change to the average, the color of its background is changed and then doesn't react if the value changes again. So values and colors are working fine for all cells except where we have a function in the cell: the values change but the color changes once and then remains as is. Thank you in advance @Rory

Comment: If you have formulas in cells, a recalculation does not trigger the Change event, only the Calculate event. Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 2013, any suggestions please? Thanks a million @Rory

Comment: Why don't you use conditional formatting to colour the cells then?